# Django/Views executing two forms

Tags: python, django

I'm really having some trouble with this. I've got some custom user's setup and those users can be attached to companies via foreign key. I'm just having trouble saving them. I've tried a ton of different variations of getting the user attached to a company and I just can't crack it.  The forms do work and it does both create a "customer" and a "customer company".

I know this needs to be a variation of:

```
if customer_form.is_valid() and customer_company_form.is_valid():
    customer_company = customer_company_form.save()
    customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
    customer.user = customer_company
    customer_company.save()
```

models.py

```
class CustomerCompany(models.Model):
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('USA', 'United States'),
        ('CAN', 'Canada')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    state = USStateField(blank=True, null=True)
    us_zipcode = USZipCodeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ca_province = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    ca_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    country =models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES,
                                    blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:customer_company_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            primary_key=True, related_name='customer_profile')
    company = models.ForeignKey(CustomerCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomerSignupForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.is_customer = True
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.save()
        customer = Customer.objects.create(user=user)
        customer.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        customer.save()
        return user

class CustomerCompanyCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ca_province = CAProvinceField(required=False, label="Province")
    ca_postal_code = CAPostalCodeField(required=False, label="Postal Code")
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerCompany
        fields = ['name', 'website', 'phone', 'address', 'city', 'state',
                'us_zipcode', 'country', 'ca_province', 'ca_postal_code']
        labels = {
            "us_zipcode": "Zipcode",
        }
```

views.py **Updated with working code**

```
def customer_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer_form = CustomerSignupForm(request.POST)
        customer_company_form = CustomerCompanyCreateForm(request.POST)
        if customer_form.is_valid() and customer_company_form.is_valid():
            # first save the user object
            user_obj = customer_form.save(commit=False)
            # Then use this object to get to my Customer model via the related name
            customer = user_obj.customer_profile
            # now save the CustomerCompany
            company = customer_company_form.save()
            # attach the customer to the Company
            customer.company = company
            # now fully save the customer after he's attached to his company
            customer.save()
            return redirect('customer_dashboard:customer_dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the errors below.')
    else:
        customer_form = CustomerSignupForm()
        customer_company_form = CustomerCompanyCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration/customer_signup_combined.html', {
                'customer_form' : customer_form,
                'customer_company_form' : customer_company_form,
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving both forms in your view but you're not connecting the two objects.
Calling save on the `customer_form` will return a `User` object since its a `User` `ModelForm`. You can use this object to get to the `Customer` object via the `customer_profile` `related_name` and set the `company` field to the `Company` instance returned when you save the `customer_company_form`.

It should look like this:

```
if customer_form.is_valid() and customer_company_form.is_valid():
    user_obj = customer_form.save(commit=True)
    customer = user_obj.customer_profile
    company = customer_company_form.save(commit=True)
    customer.company = company
    customer.save()
    return redirect('customer_dashboard:customer_dashboard')
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked with one small tweak.  the commit=False on the customer_company_form I had to remove and now it's working perfectly. I've updated my code above.